# Automatically checking retracted papers in bibliography

Tags: citations, code, retraction

Is there a program or online service to automatically check if there is a retracted paper in the bibliography of a pdf file?

Comment: First of all, is there any program / service that is able to reliably check whether a given paper is retracted?

Comment: [RetractionWatch](https://retractionwatch.com/) launched a database of retracted papers: http://retractiondatabase.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure a tool for this exists at the moment, but the open [database of retracted papers](http://retractiondatabase.org/RetractionSearch.aspx?) from [Retraction Watch](https://retractionwatch.com/) is a great place to search for retracted papers--AFAIK it's the major database of retractions anywhere, and it's free to use.

If anyone is interested in developing tools for interfacing with the database, I bet they would be amenable (I am not affiliated with Retraction Watch, just appreciate the work they do).

Answer (score 3):

If you import the bibliography into Zotero it will automatically do so for any document with a DOI or PMID: https://www.zotero.org/blog/retracted-item-notifications/

as an example:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of today, nothing for free, and definitely nothing for PDF files. The best approach to developing such a program would be writing a front-end to the database of an organization such as Thomson Reuters or DBLP. However, you are unlikely to get free access to the interface of the database.